# VIM UI language issue

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vim, terminal

I am using VIM for a while, but never faces such a problem.

When i connect to my desktop Ubuntu PC via ssh from a tablet (Asus tf Prime) using terminal emulator (screen-256-colors) I got my vim in Chinese... On desktop it is correctly working in English.

I've tried to set

```
set langmenu=en_US.UTF-8
language en_US.UTF-8
```

but it do not help... See screenshot[image]

You may find my configuration on [github](https://github.com/AlexParamonov/config)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in bad linux package installed on desktop - vim-gnome 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1

I've removed it and build vim from sources. And now have no issues at all. Setting "set langmenu" is not needed anymore: vim works great without it.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
language message en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it help?